# get component error Unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Here is my script that I keep getting null reference exception, but I don't know what to do? What do I assign where?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CurrencyManagment : MonoBehaviour {

public int Coins;
public CreditPlayer CreditPlayerScript;

void Start ()
{
    CreditPlayerScript = GetComponent<CreditPlayer>();

}

void Awake()
{
    CreditPlayerScript = GetComponent<CreditPlayer>();

}

void Update ()
{
    Coins = CreditPlayerScript.CoinsTempContainer;

}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually have a `CreditPlayer` component attached to the object that uses `CurrencyManagement`?

Comment: @Will I have a script called credit player and as stated in the start function   CreditPlayerScript = GetComponent<CreditPlayer>(); that line assigns it doesent it??

Comment: No,  that line retrieves a component already attached to the object.

Comment: @wiz3kid so what do I need to do I am a little confused sorry??

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have a `CreditPlayer` script attached to the same Game Object that you have a `CurrencyManager`. Simply drag and drop the script to the Game Object (with the game stopped, not running).

You can also do it programatically, by adding a `RequireComponent` attribute that will automatically add all scripts you specify. Take a look at [this document](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html).

Comment: Okay but now when the coin is destroyed both scripts go with it. I need the Player to run into the coin and the currency management script stored elsewhere so that the Currency management script is not destroyed with the coin. @Roberto

Comment: @user3682512 in that case you need to make the CurrencyManagement a regular global class,  not a component.

Comment: @user3682512 yeah wiz3kid is right. Google "singleton", that's what you need.